# File upload in chunks using Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, chunks

Is there any directive available in Angular4/Angular2, which supports file upload in chunks?

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow .Please go through https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest befor e posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what server you using. But I advice to take a look at  File api, [click](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Server side, PHP API receive data into chunks. Chunks is necessary because upload file size is approx more than 70MB.